# CMake link to external library

Tags: cmake

How to get CMake to link an executable to an external shared library that is not build within the same CMake project?

Just doing `target_link_libraries(GLBall ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res/mylib.so)` gives the error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `res/mylib.so', needed by `GLBall'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GLBall.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
(GLBall is the executable)
```

after I copied the library into the binary dir `bin/res`.

I tried using `find_library(RESULT mylib.so PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res)`

Which fails with `RESULT-NOTFOUND`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Set libraries search path first:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res)
```

And then just do

```
target_link_libraries(GLBall mylib)
```

Comment: The use of [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:link_directories) is discouraged, even in its own documentation. I think it would be better here to resolve the failing `find_library` call in the original question, or use @Andre's solution.

Comment: I find the "imported" library target to be more robust, as it targets the location of the particular library, instead simply giving a global search path.  See Andre's answer.

Comment: You should always use `find_library` and use this path instead of hard coding it, cf. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2799037).

Comment: most people coming here just want to make -lm work.   They won't even know the library name.

Answer (score 171):

arrowdodger's answer is correct and preferred on many occasions. I would simply like to add an alternative to his answer:

You could add an "imported" library target, instead of a link-directory. Something like:

```
# Your-external "mylib", add GLOBAL if the imported library is located in directories above the current.
add_library( mylib SHARED IMPORTED )
# You can define two import-locations: one for debug and one for release.
set_target_properties( mylib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res/mylib.so )
```

And then link as if this library was built by your project:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(GLBall mylib)
```

Such an approach would give you a little more flexibility: Take a look at the [add_library(  IMPORTED)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) command and the [many target-properties related to imported libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets).

I do not know if this will solve your problem with "updated versions of libs".

Comment: That would probably be
`add_library( mylib SHARED IMPORTED )`
or you get an `add_library called with IMPORTED argument but no library type` error

Comment: @Andre: I think after `IMPORTED_LOCATION` the opening bracket is wrong

Comment: you need to add `GLOBAL` after `IMPORTED` if you want to access the imported library in directories above the current: `add_library(breakpad STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)`

Comment: @Andre IMPORTED_LOCATION seems to require the path to the file instead of the directory containing the file

Comment: @SOUser: Yes, IMPORTED_LOCATION should point to the file, not to the directory. I have fixed that, guess the author won't complain.

Comment: I really don't know why those basic usage not supported by offical clearly! Thanks

Comment: ```(target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "mylib" which is not built by
this project.
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed```

Why am I getting this error? can anyone help?

Comment: This answer is decent, but could be great with three adjustments: (1) by adding a visibility specifier to `target_link_libraries` (2) by adding `::` somewhere in the name of the `IMPORTED` target and (3) by using `find_library` to determine the value of the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property.

Answer (score 115):

I assume you want to link to a library called *foo*, its filename is usually something link `foo.dll` or `libfoo.so`.

**1. Find the library**
You have to find the library. This is a good idea, even if you know the path to your library. CMake will error out if the library vanished or got a new name. This helps to spot error early and to make it clear to the user (may yourself) what causes a problem.
To find a library *foo* and store the path in `FOO_LIB` use

```
    find_library(FOO_LIB foo)
```

CMake will figure out itself how the actual file name is. It checks the usual places like `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64` and the paths in `PATH`.

You already know the location of your library. Add it to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when you call CMake, then CMake will look for your library in the passed paths, too.

Sometimes you need to add hints or path suffixes, see the documentation for details:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html

**2. Link the library**
From 1. you have the full library name in `FOO_LIB`. You use this to link the library to your target `GLBall` as in

```
  target_link_libraries(GLBall PRIVATE "${FOO_LIB}")
```

You should add `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC`, or `INTERFACE` after the target, cf. the documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

If you don't add one of these visibility specifiers, it will either behave like `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC`, depending on the CMake version and the policies set.

**3. Add includes** *(This step might be not mandatory.)*
If you also want to include header files, use `find_path` similar to `find_library` and search for a header file. Then add the include directory with `target_include_directories` similar to `target_link_libraries`.

Documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html
and
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

If available for the external software, you can replace `find_library` and `find_path` by `find_package`.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer. However, I had trouble because I wasn't calling "find_library" after "project" and "target_link_libraries" after "add_executable".

Comment: `find_package` is so much simpler than following these steps

Comment: I guess I don't understand step 2. For a shared library ${FOO_LIB} will be like /full/path/to/libfoo.dylib. How is that useful? target_link_libraries is not creating "-L/full/path/to -lfoo", so find_library is not returning anything useful, other than verifying that the library is in the location where I already know it is. What am I missing?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(mylib "${FOO_LIB}")`? The target is `mylib` instead of his actual target, `GLBall`? doesn't make much sense to me

Answer (score 16):

Let's say you have an executable like:

```
add_executable(GLBall GLBall.cpp)
```

If the external library has headers, give the path to its include folder:

```
target_include_directories(GLBall PUBLIC "/path/to/include")
```

Add the library directory path:

```
target_link_directories(GLBall PUBLIC "/path/to/lib/directory")
```

Finally, link the library name

```
target_link_libraries(GLBall mylib)
```

Note that the prefix and extension of the library file are removed:

libmylib.a ➜ mylib
mylib.so ➜ mylib

Comment: Your answer worked for me! It was a different use case, but I was really really stuck until I tried your way :)

Comment: Is it safe to also assume that mylib.a -> mylib?

Comment: @david-c ld will prefer mylib.so over my lib.a if you did not specify --static.

Answer (score 5):

One more alternative, in the case you are working with the Appstore, need "Entitlements" and as such need to link with an Apple-Framework.

For Entitlements to work (e.g. GameCenter) you *need* to have a "Link Binary with Libraries"-buildstep and then link with "GameKit.framework". CMake "injects" the libraries on a "low level" into the commandline, hence Xcode doesn't *really* know about it, and as such you will *not* get GameKit enabled in the Capabilities screen.

One way to use CMake and have a "Link with Binaries"-buildstep is to generate the xcodeproj with CMake, and then use 'sed' to 'search & replace' and add the GameKit in the way XCode likes it...

The script looks like this (for Xcode 6.3.1).

```
s#\/\* Begin PBXBuildFile section \*\/#\/\* Begin PBXBuildFile section \*\/\
    26B12AA11C10544700A9A2BA \/\* GameKit.framework in Frameworks \*\/ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 26B12AA01C10544700A9A2BA \/\* GameKit.framework xxx\*\/; };#g

s#\/\* Begin PBXFileReference section \*\/#\/\* Begin PBXFileReference section \*\/\
    26B12AA01C10544700A9A2BA \/\* GameKit.framework xxx\*\/ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; name = GameKit.framework; path = System\/Library\/Frameworks\/GameKit.framework; sourceTree = SDKROOT; };#g

s#\/\* End PBXFileReference section \*\/#\/\* End PBXFileReference section \*\/\
\
\/\* Begin PBXFrameworksBuildPhase section \*\/\
    26B12A9F1C10543B00A9A2BA \/\* Frameworks \*\/ = {\
        isa = PBXFrameworksBuildPhase;\
        buildActionMask = 2147483647;\
        files = (\
            26B12AA11C10544700A9A2BA \/\* GameKit.framework in Frameworks xxx\*\/,\
        );\
        runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;\
    };\
\/\* End PBXFrameworksBuildPhase section \*\/\
#g

s#\/\* CMake PostBuild Rules \*\/,#\/\* CMake PostBuild Rules \*\/,\
            26B12A9F1C10543B00A9A2BA \/\* Frameworks xxx\*\/,#g
s#\/\* Products \*\/,#\/\* Products \*\/,\
            26B12AA01C10544700A9A2BA \/\* GameKit.framework xxx\*\/,#g
```

save this to "gamecenter.sed" and then "apply" it like this ( it changes your xcodeproj! )

```
sed -i.pbxprojbak -f gamecenter.sed myproject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

You might have to change the script-commands to fit your need.

Warning: it's likely to break with different Xcode-version as the project-format could change, the (hardcoded) unique number might not really by unique - and generally the solutions by other people are better - so unless you need to Support the Appstore + Entitlements (and automated builds), don't do this.

This is a CMake bug, see http://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14185 and http://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14185

Comment: Specifically - getting cmake to link with an external library is not the problem (there are several solutions above). Getting this to work in an automated way, so that it works with the Apple Appstore *and* entitlements is a challenge. In that specific case, the above solutions do not work because XCode will not 'see' the libraries linked in that way, and entitlements will just not work. Afaik cmake can't add the libaries the way xcode needs it in an 'appstore-compatible way'- again, feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Oh, that's sad. For completeness the link to the new issue tracker, which does currently contain no commnets: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14185

Comment: The problem was solved 5 month ago, so with a recent version of CMake it should no longer be present. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14185

Comment: Fixed in CMake 3.19, to be specific.